# A word or term for extrapolation fallacy or using results beyond their context? [Solved]

Tags: expressions, logic

I am looking for a word or term that means something like:

- you are using previous results outside boundaries of the original experiment/observation
- earlier experience/results does not apply in all other cases
- you are extrapolating findings beyond original context
- those specific test results don't apply to every case
- there is no evidence that previous observations apply in all other cases
- those findings cannot be applied here
- it does not follow that...

For example - someone has measured some attribute and concluded it increases efficiency (ignoring correlation and causality) - then extrapolate to claim that all other cases would benefit from increasing this attribute. I want to say that is not true, because the original observation applied to specific situation and it's faulty logic or extrapolating too much to assume the same thing works everywhere.

I Found a [list of fallacies on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_fallacies)- the ones that I think are most appropriate are: Faulty Generalization, Hasty Generalization, Fallacy of Composition and Inductive Fallacy

Comment: Sounds like someone is overgeneralizing.

Comment: How about "exaggeration" ? :))

Comment: Your assumptions do not hold in the extrapolated region.

Comment: I think that "unwarranted extrapolation" covers the situation pretty well.

Comment: I think the over-generalizing is good.
Thanks everyone!